# VS2010 doesn't "see" any of the tests in a new test class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I've created a class of Unit tests in an existing project (as opposed to creating a whole new test project)

When trying to run the tests via the Test menu VS claims that no tests are loaded..

How do I solve this ? (except for rewriting all the unit tests in Nunit, that is )

**Editing** to answer the questions:
the class and methods are public, [TestClass] and [TestMethod] annotations are all there

```
[TestClass]
    public class FunctionalTests
    {        

        [ClassInitialize()]
        public void ClassInit()
        {
            //do init stuff
        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void TestSomething()
        {
           //testing stuff
        }
```

Comment: Please post the code for the new test class.

Comment: Are test methods public?

Comment: The class must be public too.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the class has the `[TestClass]` attribute and that the tests methods has the `[TestMethod]` attribute. It happened to me once and this was the problem.

Comment: Yup, all there. I suspect the problem is the tests being in a "regular" project and not a separate test project ...

Comment: It could be ... why do you want to have together tests and production code?

Comment: The unit tests are not testing the code they share the project with, but they use the utils from it. Perhaps it's not the best structure, indeed..

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on trying to get sround VS2010 and created a new separate project for the tests, and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

The `ClassInitialize` and `ClassCleanup` methods need to be `static`.

```
    [ClassInitialize()]
    public static void ClassInit()
    {
    }

    [ClassCleanup]
    public static void ClassCleanup()
    {
    }
```

Comment: thanks, changed that later on- as it wasn't part of the original problem